# How to add Drop-Down Sub-Menu

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am almost done with my navigation panel.

How am gonna add a sub-menu to this. I have my Sub-menu at the Product page.

Here's the HTML with the sub-menus in it:

```
<nav>

<ul>

    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">T-SHIRTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MUGS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CUPS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">JEANS</a></li>            
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>

 </ul>


 </nav>
```

Here my CSS:

```
 nav{
   width:1000px;
   height:50px;
   background-color:#333;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
   font-family: NeoSans;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 nav ul{
   list-style: none;
 }

 nav ul ul{
   display: none;
 }

 nav ul li{
   display: inline;
   float: left;
 }

 nav ul li a{
   color: #CCC;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 40px 41px 40px 41px;    
 }

 nav ul li a:hover{
   color: #F60;
   background-color: #000;
 }
```

Thank you guys for the nice hand!

More Power!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, but also you have to change some style of `anchor` like `padding` and some other things :

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
}
ul ul li {
    width: 120px;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://eimaung.com/professional-web-developer/html/ch3/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .nav, .sub {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .nav li {
      background: #cb1212;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 160px;
    }
    .nav li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .nav li a:hover {
      background: #f00;
    }
    .nav > li {
      border-right: 1px solid #f00;
      float: left;
    }
    .sub {
      display: none;
    }
    .nav > li:hover .sub {
      display: block;
    }
    .sub li {
      border-top: 1px solid #f00;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Services &raquo;</a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your css and update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/9B9NS/)

**html**

```
<nav>

<ul>

    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">T-SHIRTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">MUGS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CUPS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">JEANS</a></li>            
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>

 </ul>


 </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
   width:1000px;
   height:50px;
   background-color:#333;
   font-family: NeoSans;
   line-height:50px;
 }

 nav ul,  nav ul li{
   list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 }

 nav ul li ul{
   display: none;
 }

 nav ul li{
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   position:relative;
 }

 nav ul li a{
   color: #CCC;
   text-decoration: none;   
   padding:0 10px;
    display:block;
 }

 nav ul li a:hover{
   color: #F60;
   background-color: #000;
 }
 nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    top:51px;
    background:#333;
    text-align:left;
 }
 nav ul ul li{
     float:none;
    display:block;
 }
 nav ul ul li a{
     padding:0;
    disbplay:block;
    padding:0 10px;
 }
```